# PrestaShop add address form with invisible required fields

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm having some issues with the add address form on a PrestaShop 1.6 based store. In some conditions (I still don't know which), the form is shown to the user without the postal code and state fields but with an extra VAT "intra-community" number field that usually not appear. Altough, when the user tries to submit the form, a few errors appear saying that those "invisible" fields (postal code and state) are not correctly filled. Any hint? Thanks

Comment: @headmax extra VAT? I don't know what you are talking about. Sorry

Comment: oh I see, just checked and it's already unistalled so that's not the problem.

Comment: when you talk about the form which one are you talking because you got forms in admin in front.

Comment: I'm talking about the front-office form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158030/discussion-between-headmax-and-notgeek).

Comment: Did you installed recently an extension, how the problem appears? any logs in your server logs php, apache2, mysql errors logs. I suggest you to do a versioning using git or svn because in this situation you have just revert to back in the last stable prestashop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figured out what the problem was. Basically this was happening when the user has JavaScript disabled. Also, the VAT field appears when the user fills the Company field.